# Cannot find "restart any running service" in SQL Server Services

Tags: sql-server

After I stoped and restarted again SQL Server, I cannot connect to SQL Server, this is error:

[image]

As recommended, I folowed the steps below:

- Start the SQL Configuration Manager (ie: Start->Programs->SQL
  Server->Configuration Tools)
- Expand the SQL native Client
  configuration Click Client Protocols (you may have a 32-bit and a
  64-bit, apply to both)
- Ensure Shared memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes are
  enabled in that order
- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
- Ensure Shared Memory for either SQLEXPRESS and/or MSSQLSERVER is enabled
- Click SQL Server Services
- Restart any running services

But in the last step, I saw "SQL Server Services" but I dont know how to `Restart any running services.`

[image]

Click right on `SQL Server Services` but no helpful option here, help!!!

Comment: Have you checked Services under Control Panel > Admin Tools (alternatively, you can go to the RUN dialog and type services.msc).  Scroll down to SQL* and make sure SQL Server is started.  Also, it looks like you have two instances.  Have you tried connecting to `.\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: Right-click "SQL Server Services" in MSSQL Config Mgr should say "Start", "Stop" and "Restart".  Q: How did you stop it?  From MSSQL Config Mgr?  Q: Did you do "anything else" besides just stop it?  Q: Have you tried rebooting?  Q: Have you looked for errors in the Windows event logs or the MSSQL logs?

Comment: @AdamPlocher As you recommended, I've checked Services under Control Panel--> status: running. Is that right status>

Comment: @paulsm4 I right click --> the options is: open/view/refresh/export list/help. There is no Start or Stop option. I stoped it last night after connected to SQL

Comment: Try the solution suggest at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/569ee2d4-0805-40e2-a4f0-10f7d573fd75/sql-server-configuration-manager-remote-procedure-call-failed0x800706be?forum=sqltools

Answer (score 0):

There may be few things that may be causing this problem may be RPC is not enabled on your system, As your error says ("*The  remote procedure call failed*") or  may be your firewall is not configured correctly.
So i suggest you to check few things like

**1** Check if Remote Connections are enabled on your SQL Server database [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) .
**2** If a firewall is turned on but not correctly configured, attempts to connect to SQL 
       Server might be blocked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx).

--Hope it helps.